# Bootstrapの検索フォームがiPhoneで表示が崩れる

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrapを使い、[このサイト](https://nllllll.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-searchform/)を参考に検索フォームを作成した。

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="search-form" class="form-control input-group-prepend" placeholder="キーワードを入力"></input>
    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-append">
        <submit type="submit" id="btn-search" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clickSearch()">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i> 検索
        </submit>
    </span>
</div>
```

PCでみると、
[image: PCから]

このように理想通りに表示されるが、スマホ(iPhone)で見てみると、
[image: iPhoneから]

このように検索ボタンの表示が崩れてしまう。
ちなみに、これはスマホのsafariでもChromeでも同じだった。
なぜでしょうか。お力添え願います

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submit` タグはサファリで表示が変わるから、bootsrapを使う場合は `submit` タグを `button` タグにした方がいいかな。下記のコードを使ってみてください。

詳しくは以下のページも参照してください。

[Button addons - Input group · Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons)

```
  <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="txt-search" class="form-control input-group-prepend" placeholder="キーワードを入力">
        <span class="input-group-btn input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" id="btn-search" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> 検索</button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

or

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"></path>
            </svg>
            検索
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```